# what exactly nginx_ingress_controller_request_duration_seconds tells

Tags: prometheus, nginx-ingress, promql

I have been playing around a lot with nginx/ingress metrics for prometheus. There is no official documentation AFAIK on the metrics and its quite difficult to understand the details of each metric.
For eg:

`nginx_ingress_controller_request_duration_seconds` and `nginx_ingress_controller_response_duration_seconds`

What exactly these tell me, 1st one is it the total time for processing the request and the latter one is time for processing response and sending last byte of it? Also few people says the value is in milliseconds.

Other question is basically I want to find out the average active request time taken for nginx.

Can someone please elaborate on these questions. ! Also just a note that I have no intentions to use Nginx Plus if you are suggesting for more metrics :)

Comment: You share with us same metrics. Both are the same name, typo?

Comment: The questions was answered [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6650)